# How to get request attributes of action tag in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, attributes, httprequest

I have my action executing by Struts `<s:action>` tag in my JSP page.

```jsp
<s:action name="test" ignoreContextParams="false" executeResult="false" namespace="/">
  <h1><s:property value="#attr.testname" /></h1>
</s:action>
```

In the `test` action, I try to set `testname` attribute to a value, like following code.

```java
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServletActionContext.getRequest().setAttribute("testname",
            "This is a test name");
    System.out.println("test action executing");
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

From the output of information, the action executed, but `<h1></h1>` is empty. Also I have try

```jsp
<h1><s:property value="#request.testname"/></h1>
```

But I can not get the result I want, still empty.

How can I get those attributes executing in `<s:action />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `property` tag after the `action` tag. Until the body of the `action` tag is evaluated the context variables might not be available.

```jsp
<s:action name="test" ignoreContextParams="false" executeResult="false" namespace="/"/>
<h1><s:property value="#attr.testname" /></h1>
```